# ArrayList<Integer>. Boxing perfomance?

Tags: java, performance, arraylist

I'm writing an application which will process a large amount of data and I need an `ArrayList<Integer>` functionality. I want to rewrite `ArrayList` class in order to work with an `int` type, instead of an `Integer` class. How much will this improve performance?

Comment: It will do improve since no GC only native.

Comment: No idea but you could probably rewrite the class fairly quickly and test it. (Most likely just a couple of search and replaces and remove the generics)

Comment: It entirely depends on *how* you use the `ArrayList`. Also, there are already implementations for "primitive" collections, such as fastutil.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Integer auto-unboxing and auto-boxing gives performance issues?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037389/integer-auto-unboxing-and-auto-boxing-gives-performance-issues)

Comment: Please do a minimal effort before posting. Just googling "java autoboxing performance" gives you lots of information.

Comment: see this for a stopwatch class which can be used to find which class is faster http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255738/is-there-a-stopwatch-in-java (note:stopwatch is not 100% accurate)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel.

It was done long time ago :)

http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/list/array/TIntArrayList.html

it works great.

[benchmarks](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/html/benchmarks.shtml)

Comment: No problem, I'm using Trove myself for the same reason - big amount of data that's needs to be stored in memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<int[]> arlist=new ArrayList<int[]>();
int ar1[]={1,2,3};
arlist.add(0,ar1);
```

Isnt this plausible?

Comment: Not really :-)  That's not functionally equivalent to a list of Integer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do this.  See @dantuch's Answer.

I just want to point out the *problems* with using a specialized "list of `int`" class.

- The class cannot be API compatible with the standard collection classes and interfaces.  If you are trying to use some other API that requires a `Collection` or a `List`, then the specialized class cannot be used with it.
- You won't be able to use polymorphism across the various "list of primitive" types.